# I have a stock list in excel

Tags: excel, formula, hidden

I have a stock list in excel. I'm using a formula `=IF(E7=0,"-",D6+B7+C7-E7)` which is fine as long as I enter a number in cell E7 but I need to get the calculation when I enter a value in B7 and/or C7. The formula is in cell D7 but I don't want formula results to be displayed in the cells below until there are more entries. Can you help please?

[image: Kit Stock]

Comment: Just throw more IF testing at it until you get what you need: `=IF(AND(B7 + C7 <> 0, E7=0), D6+B7+C7, IF(E7=0, "-", D6+B7+C7-E7))` That's an IF inside an IF. The outer IF tests for two things to be true. I'm certain this isn't exactly what you need, but it should get you close.

Comment: Thanks but still not getting it - will keep trying!

Comment: It can get confusing with all the nested testing. My example says "If B7 plus C7 is equal to 0 AND E7 is equal to 0, then add up D6, B7, and C7. Otherwise if E7 is equal to 0 then stick a dash. If none of those things happened, then go ahead andd up D6, B7, and C7 and substract E7." If you could explain more exactly what you are testing for and what you expect the output to be just as I did here where I wrote it out, we would be happy to write up the formula that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a dash, you could return an empty String. For example:

```
=IF(E7=0,"",D6+B7+C7-E7)
```

This will not display anything in a particular row in column D until there is a value in the corresponding row in column E.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you input an "Original Stock" column in B to account for the numers that don't add up in your example:

[image: Data table with "Original Stock" inserted in Column B]

In that case, this formula should do the trick:

```
=IF(AND(B2=0,C2=0,D2=0,F2=0),"",B2+C2+D2-F2)
```

It checks to see if colums B and C and D and F are empty and outputs an empty cell if they are. Otherwise, you get the current stock from these cells.

Is this close to what you wanted to achieve?

You can download my test file
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1aub9xrnnhizsg/StockCalc.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you this looks good. Will give it a try - Sorry not to respond  sooner but I've tried so many variations I'd given up the will to live! Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Your example looks perfect but when I did exactly the same it comes up with an error message saying error in formula (it highlights the 0 in B2=0) I've tried with "0" but same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: My bad, actually. I live in Norway, where comma is decimal point. Therefore we use semicolon to separate arguments in formulas instead of commas. Exchange all semicolons in the formula with comma. Original answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have got the code working at last. but how do I stop all the formula results showing in the cells below. I need to return an empty string somehow. Formula is   =IF(AND(B5,C5,E5="0"),"",B5+C5+D4-E5)

Comment: I dono't get formula results in below cells in my test file. I have added a link to it in my original answer. See if it works on your end.

Comment: Oh, and I see an error in your formula. You have E5 instead of D5 in the and expression and E5 instead of F5 at the end. This should be correct: `=IF(AND(B5,C5,D5,F5="0"),"",B5+C5+D4-F5)`

Comment: Thank you for your patience Lars, I've got it sorted now, you've been very helpful. Wendy

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working :) Excel formulas are notoriously difficult to understand, so no worries. If you could use the answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the question so I can get credit for it ;) Thank you, Wendy